# WPF How to make a textbox slideable

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a TextBox with fixed height and width.
I want to have a slider or something else on the TextBox to make the missing text visible. 
By missing text I mean the text that is longer than the width of the TextBox.
It doesn't have to be a slider just something that allows me to see the cut text.

I tried:

```
<TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

but it does nothing for me.

Comment: Have you tried setting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=Auto"` ? The vertical scroll bar won't show unless the text is multi-line, and if it's not wrapping, it could all be on one line.

Comment: if i add this ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" nothing happens i see no scrollbar or anything

Comment: How about adding a tooltip?

Comment: I want to Change the value in the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
<TextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        Width="300"
        Height="200"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        AcceptsReturn="True"
        FontSize="22pt"
        Text="Some loooooooooong text. Some loooooooooong text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. "
        />
```

The key here is setting `TextWrapping="Wrap"`. Also, if you want to be able to make a new line with the ENTER key, set `AcceptsReturn="True"`.

If the scroll bar doesn't show for you, maybe your `Width` and `Height` isn't as "fixed" as you thought. The size of `ScrollViewer` needs to be limited somehow. Make sure that your `TextBox` is properly positioned in its container. For example, you may temporarily set its `BorderThickness="5"` and see if it isn't clipped anywhere (this may be the case if you have any `HorizontalAlignment` / `VerticalAlignment`  other than `Stretch`).

---

**EDIT:**

As I mentioned, for scrolling a `TextBox`, all depends on the value of `TextWrapping` property.

For a `TextBox`, scrolling horizontally out-of-the-box only only makes sense if the text isn't wrapped (meaning there's only one very long line):

```
    <TextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Width="300"
        Height="200"
        TextWrapping="NoWrap"
        FontSize="22pt"
        Text="Some loooooooooong text. Some loooooooooong text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. "
        />
```

If you want to have more than one line of text to scroll it horizontally, you have to wrap a `TextBox` in a `ScrollViewer` explicitly and set the sizes correctly to limit the `ScrollViewer`'s content:

```
<ScrollViewer 
        Width="200"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <TextBox Name="txb1"
            Width="500"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            FontSize="22pt"
            Text="Some loooooooooong text. Some loooooooooong text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. "
        />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I guess if you want to "auto-adjust" the width of the `TextBox` somehow, you'd need to calculate it as text changes. A way to do it off the top of my head (there are probably better solutions):

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        txb1.Width = txb1.Text.Split('\n').Max(a =>a.Length) * approximatedCharWidth;
    }
```

where as `approximatedCharWidth` I used:

```
approximatedCharWidth = MeasureString(txb1, "lext").Width/4.0;
private Size MeasureString(TextBox textBlock, string candidate)
    {
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(
            candidate,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(textBlock.FontFamily, textBlock.FontStyle, textBlock.FontWeight, textBlock.FontStretch),
            textBlock.FontSize,
            Brushes.Black,
            new NumberSubstitution(),
            1);

        return new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);
}
```

Comment: It only works for the verticalscrollbar. If i set vertical to disabled and horizontal to Auto it does nothing. Copy pasted your TextBox.

Comment: You solved it thank you. But now the scrollbar takes too much space. Is there another solution beside scrollbar ? Maybe by clicking on the TextBox it gets bigger and when i leave it it gets smaller again.

Comment: @Explorer2501 you can style the scrollbar however you want (also its sizes), although it can be a bit of a challenge. If you have Expression Blend I think it is easier. Anyway, you can find out how to do it by searching "wpf styling scrollviewer" or "wpf custom scrollviewer" on Google. Here is an example https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/styling-a-scrollviewerscrollbar-in-wpf/

Comment: @Explorer2501 you may also hide/show it depending on TextBox.IsFocused property, for example writing a converter (that converts bool to ScrollBarVisibility). Bind HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding ElementName=txb1, Path=IsFocused, Converter={converters:Converter_BoolToScrollBarVisibility}}

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a plain string with no line feeds then this can only work for horizontal OR vertical scrolling.

If you can scroll horizontally then you're telling the text it can be as wide as it likes. Which means you will get one line.

If you instead wanted it to go across multiple lines then you either need linefeeds in the text or avoid any horizontal scrolling.

Seeing as you don't seem to want vertical scrolling I tried this:

```
     <TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             Text="ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
             Height="36"
             Width="200"
             />
```

Which gives:

[image: A horizontal scrolling textbox]

Which seems to be what you're after.